# SQL : Distinct on one column with multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

Hello after hours of searching on the website, I've not found my answer!

### I created a query on MySQL I want to display every column who contains one time an id but this query repeatedly displays the same id. I suspect it's because of the column date. But I don't know how to fix that!

|groups.id|name|date    |dateend

|12345678 |abc |12/12/09|12/12/09

|12345678 |abc |13/01/23|13/01/23

|23456677 |bdc |01/01/18|01/01/18

I want this output :

|groups.id|name|date    |dateend

|12345678 |abc |12/12/09|12/12/09

|23456677 |bdc |01/01/18|01/01/18

Thanks in advance!

```
SELECT DISTINCT (projects_prj.uuid_group_prj),groups.country_alpha2_prj,
          groups.title_prj,projects_prj.start_prj,projects_prj.end_prj,crisis.toDate,
          crisis.fromDate,crisis.calculationType,crisis.level,crisis.reportlink,
          groups.location_prj_lat,groups.location_prj_long,crisis.long_disaster,
          crisis.lat_disaster,kml_link,
     get_distance_metres(groups.location_prj_lat,groups.location_prj_long,crisis.lat_disaster,crisis.long_disaster)/1000 as km
            FROM `projects_prj`, groups,crisis
            WHERE groups.uuid_group_prj= projects_prj.uuid_group_prj
            and projects_prj.status_prj ='FREE'
            and projects_prj.end_prj >= NOW()
            and crisis.toDate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY
            and (groups.location_prj_lat <= crisis.lat_disaster +1 AND groups.location_prj_lat >= crisis.lat_disaster -1) AND (groups.location_prj_long <= crisis.long_disaster +1 AND groups.location_prj_long >= crisis.long_disaster - 1)
```

[Result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAAc1.png)

Comment: What would help you ask? Sample data, expected result and MySQL version. Thanks, StackOverflow community ;)

Comment: Thx for your answer ! I would like the id to be displayed once !

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function, it is a modifier; it also operates on whole rows. With `DISTINCT x, y`, you can have (1, 1), (1, 2), and (2, 1), not additional rows with (1, 1). It is not exactly clear what you are talking about since you say "same id", but no fields you've shown have "id" in them. It is probably worth noting that queries should not be looked at as "displaying" anything; they provide data, and that data may be repeated, whether it is shown or not should be handled by the client application/code.

Comment: Assuming you wanted each value for `projects_prj.uuid_group_prj` to be shown only once; how would you know what the value is on result rows that hid the value? _(Also: Your result does not make sense when compared the query you've shown; the column counts are drastically different.)_

Comment: You haven't given any indication as to how the rows should be selected. Since you've selected all the columns, I assume you want all that data... So which do we keep? The most recent? The first?

Comment: Hello, sorry if it's not clear, with this query i want to display every project who is impacted by a disaster. This query works but the query returns duplicates column.

Answer (score 0):

To get the single instance of the name you can use `group by`

```
SELECT DISTINCT (projects_prj.uuid_group_prj),groups.country_alpha2_prj,
          groups.title_prj,projects_prj.start_prj,projects_prj.end_prj,crisis.toDate,
          crisis.fromDate,crisis.calculationType,crisis.level,crisis.reportlink,
          groups.location_prj_lat,groups.location_prj_long,crisis.long_disaster,
          crisis.lat_disaster,kml_link,
     get_distance_metres(groups.location_prj_lat,groups.location_prj_long,crisis.lat_disaster,crisis.long_disaster)/1000 as km
            FROM `projects_prj`, groups,crisis
            WHERE groups.uuid_group_prj= projects_prj.uuid_group_prj
            and projects_prj.status_prj ='FREE'
            and projects_prj.end_prj >= NOW()
            and crisis.toDate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY
            and (groups.location_prj_lat <= crisis.lat_disaster +1 AND groups.location_prj_lat >= crisis.lat_disaster -1) AND (groups.location_prj_long <= crisis.long_disaster +1 AND groups.location_prj_long >= crisis.long_disaster - 1)
 group by projects_prj.uuid_group_prj,Free2016.projects_prj.start_pr
 -- This may be the wrong column, but group it by that 'Name' one you have in your question
```

Comment: Hello ! Thanks for your answer ! I Tried the query with group by. But i've got this message : " Expression #4 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'Free2016.projects_prj.start_prj' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by"

Comment: This would be considered an abuse of `group by`. Most RDBMS do not allow it at all, and the more recent releases of MySQL even default the settings to disallow it. If you were to enable it in settings, it would pick effectively random choices from the values seen in the ungrouped fields for each grouping (value of uuid_group_prj).

Comment: @B.arash added the missing column, may help